# Flliper pod installation issue react native 0.62 version

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

After installing the build, every time i build the project got below error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_jump_fcontext", referenced from:
      folly::fibers::FiberImpl::deactivate() in libFlipper-Folly.a(Fiber.o)
  "_make_fcontext", referenced from:
      folly::fibers::FiberImpl::FiberImpl(folly::Function<void ()>, unsigned char*, unsigned long) in libFlipper-Folly.a(Fiber.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't know what exactly issue are.

```
def add_flipper_pods!
  version = '~> 0.74.0'
#  versions['Flipper-Glog'] ||= '0.3.6'
  pod 'FlipperKit', version, :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin', version, :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/SKIOSNetworkPlugin', version, :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin', version, :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'FlipperKit/FlipperKitReactPlugin', version, :configuration => 'Debug'
  pod 'Flipper-Glog', '0.3.6' , :configuration => 'Debug'

end



React native ver : 0.62.0

Flipper (0.87.0):
Flipper-Folly (~> 2.5)
Flipper-RSocket (~> 1.3)
Flipper-Boost-iOSX (1.76.0.1.13)
Flipper-DoubleConversion (3.1.7)
Flipper-Fmt (7.1.7)
Flipper-Folly (2.6.7):
Flipper-Boost-iOSX
Flipper-DoubleConversion
Flipper-Fmt (= 7.1.7)
Flipper-Glog
libevent (~> 2.1.12)
OpenSSL-Universal (= 1.1.180)
```

Comment: Do you have mac with M1 chip ?

Comment: @DipanSharma no i have intel chip mac

Comment: Xcode version ?

Comment: Xcode Ver 12.0.1

Comment: @DipanSharma this happened when Flipper-Boost-iOSX (1.76.0.1.13) updated from Flipper-Boost-iOSX (1.76.0.1.10)

Comment: can you please check this answer ?
https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/976

Comment: You upgraded the project to react naitve 0.62

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232477/discussion-between-chirag-shah-and-dipan-sharma).

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution which needs other flipper tools to downgrade.

##### step 1

use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.87.0', 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
add to in Podfile

##### step 2

remove Podfile.lock

##### step 3

remove Pod

##### step 4

pod install

Answer (score 0):

```
# Enables Flipper.
#
# Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
# you should disable the next line.
use_flipper!()
```

try to remove use_frameworks! in Podfile...it works for me!